# How to use text-search in mongo-spring aggregate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mongo, fulltext-index

How do I translate a simple mongo shell $match phrase, to it's equivelent
in mongo-spring in Java - using aggregation?

```
$match: { $text: { $search: "read" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-data has inbuilt support for text search.

I have used following dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Try Following Syntax :

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny("read");

Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria);    

List<klass> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, klass, "collection_name");
```

For more detail refer [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/17/text-search-your-documents-with-spring-data-mongodb).

To do the same in aggregation use following syntax :

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", 
                new BasicDBObject("$text", new BasicDBObject("$search", "COST")));

List<DBObject> aggregationList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
aggregationList.add(match);

AggregationOutput aggregationOutput = mongoTemplate.getCollection("categoryMaster")
        .aggregate(aggregationList);

List<DBObject> dbObjects = (List<DBObject>) aggregationOutput.results();
```

convert this `dbobjects` in your `klass` as below :

```
for(DBObject dbObject : dbObjects) {
    mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(klass, dbObject);
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how to do that using aggregation ?

Comment: Thanks! couldn't find this example anywhere on the web!